# How to add class to primeng panel menu when a menu/sub-menu is expanded?

Tags: css, angular, primeng, panel, primeng-menu

I use Primeng version 11 for my Angular 11 project. I am creating a panel menu using primeng and I want to add "active" class to the menu/sub-menu when it is expanded. I have tried the command in the menu but it doesn't work when multiple = false.

My primeng-panelmenu.component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MenuItem } from 'primeng/api';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-primeng-panelmenu',
  templateUrl: './primeng-panelmenu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./primeng-panelmenu.component.css'],
})
export class PrimengPanelmenuComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}
  items: MenuItem[] = [];
  ngOnInit() {
    if (true) {
      let menu = {
        label: 'File',
        icon: 'pi pi-pw pi-file',
        styleClass: '',
        command: (event) => {
          menu.styleClass = event.items.label === 'File' ? 'active' : '';
        },
        items: [
          { label: 'Open', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-external-link' },
          {
            label: 'New',
            icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-plus',
            command: (event) => {
              menu.styleClass = event.items.label === 'File' ? 'active' : '';
            },
            items: [
              { label: 'User', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-user-plus' },
              { label: 'Filter', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-filter' },
            ],
          },
          { label: 'Quit', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-times' },
        ],
      };
      this.items.push(menu);
    }
    if (true) {
      let menu = {
        label: 'Edit',
        icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-pencil',
        styleClass: '',
        command: (event) => {
          menu.styleClass = event.items.label === 'File' ? 'active' : '';
        },
        items: [
          { label: 'Delete', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-trash' },
          { label: 'Refresh', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-refresh' },
        ],
      };
      this.items.push(menu);
    }
  }
}
```

primeng-panelmenu.component.html file

```
<p-panelMenu
  [model]="items"
  [style]="{ width: '300px' }"
  [multiple]="false"
></p-panelMenu>
```

primeng-panelmenu.component.css file

```
:host ::ng-deep .active a{
  color: red !important;
}

:host ::ng-deep .active a:hover{
  color: red !important;
}
```

[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aflw.png)

Comment: Can you please provide a demo fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following should work with you:

```
a[aria-expanded="true"], a[aria-expanded="true"] .p-menuitem-text{
  color:red !important;
}
```

if it doesn't work add `:host ::ng-deep`

Comment: Thank you! It works with `:host ::ng-deep`. But it also changes the text color of the menu that doesn't have sub-menus (like the "Open") and that color does not disappear when I click other menus because the aria-expanded is still true.